# I need help understanding how to apply gradient coloring to a button using CSS

Tags: html, css, button, frontend

[image: This is the button.]

This is the button I need to create, but I have no idea how to apply multiple colors and shading effects to it. The colors used in making this button are as follows:

- Lime Green: hsl(136, 65%, 51%)
- Bright Cyan: hsl(192, 70%, 51%)

P.S. Could you also provide guidance on how to add a hover effect to this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```css
        .rounded-button {
            width: 150px;
            height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(136, 65%, 51%), hsl(192, 70%, 51%));
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50px; /* Adjust the border-radius for the degree of roundness you want */
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .rounded-button:hover {
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(192, 70%, 51%), hsl(136, 65%, 51%));
        }
```

```html
<button class="rounded-button">Request Invite</button>
```